# Storing token in global variable, or in Keychain

Tags: android, ios

The other developer and I have two different views on storing sensitive data. So, the token is only accessible at run time in a global variable right now, but I suggested moving the token to be stored in the Keychain and therefore encrypted, but he says that it is more secure to be stored as a global object because it is not being written to a file.

Currently looks like this:

> const TOKEN_STORE = {   oauth_token: "", };

What is the correct way to store a token for app development for a token that isn't needed between sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Saving toke in Keychain, which is not needed between session. I don't think it is a good idea. Better to go with Global Object. Don't save unnecessary data in keychain :)

Comment: Is it not possible to grab the token from the HEAP of the application since it is stored globally?

Comment: Yes, either you can create a parameter in AppDelegate or use Signetone.

Comment: Isn't is easier for a hacker to get memory information from the heap?